# How to restore cursor position in TinyMCE's source code view

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for a project and need to edit the HTML source code directly. However, when I switch to the source code view, I am having trouble restoring the cursor position. After editing the source code, the cursor always returns to the top of the document, which makes it difficult to continue editing from where I left off.

I've tried several methods to save and restore the cursor position, but none of them have worked so far. Is there a way to save the cursor position before switching to the source code view and then restore it after applying changes to the source code?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that may work is to use the [two events TinyMCE emits](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/events/#editor-core-events) when dialogs open and close in the editor:

`OpenWindow` – { dialog: DialogApi } – Fired when a dialog has been opened.

`CloseWindow` – { dialog: DialogApi } – Fired when a dialog has been closed.

You could have the [TinyMCE getBookmark API](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.dom.bookmarkmanager/#getBookmark) listen for the OpenWindow event, and then set the cursor position when the Close WindowEvent happens.

1. Make a selection when you want to edit the source code.
2. OpenWindow emits when code source view is active, event listener with `getBookmarkAPI` runs
3. CloseWindow runs when exiting the source code view, `moveToBookmark(variable holding the bookmark)` runs.

I'll see if I can try something out and update, but here's an article with more on TinyMCE cursor positioning https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/set-and-get-cursor-position/